# Using switch function to check for character ' in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, character

I have to make a program that allows the user to input characters then prints its decimal character code.  One of the characters is ' but when I go to check for this character it says it is missing the terminating ' character.

```
case ''':
            printf("039");
            break;
```

How do I check for ' as a charcter?

Comment: Even the most basic beginners book should have told you how to *escape* the special characters in strings and character literals.

Comment: And to nitpick a little: `switch` is a statement, not a function.

Comment: This is bizarre: the cart driving the horse. If you enter character `c` then its code is `printf("%d", c);`. You don't need 96 switch cases, just a single line.

Comment: Also be careful with using leading zeros in your numeric output. In C leading zeros means [*octal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (base 8) numbers. For an experienced C programmer the output `"039"` could be mistaken for an invalid octal number.

Comment: Drop `switch()` just use `printf("Char [%c] in ASCII [%d]\n", c, c);`

Comment: @WeatherVane: `case '\'': printf("039"); break;` always prints the ASCII code for the apostrophe character. `printf("%d", c);` prints the execution character set code for the apostrophe character, which is not always ASCII.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the question does not ask about the ASCII code. It asks about its decimal character code. Will you get off my back please?

Comment: @WeatherVane: It does not ask about the execution character set code, either; it is unspecified. The code you proposed changes the meaning of OP’s code without stating that. No, I will not stop pointing out technical issues. It is important that people learn to understand, analyze, and reason about code well. I did not even say the code you proposed was wrong; I merely stated the difference between it and the original code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an escape sequence.

```c
case '\'':
            printf("039");
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a backslash(`\`) before using `'` . Because `'` is a special character.
So, you should use as follows,

```
case '\'':
            printf("039");
            break;
```